# shell script echo back fatal error

Tags: shell, elixir

I am using Elixir's porcelain to invoke shell script, in there I have command like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
aws s3 sync frontend/dist s3://$S3_BUCKET --delete
echo
```

Now, if command fails(because of wrong bucket) it displays:

> fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidBucketName) when calling the
>   ListObjects operation: The specified bucket is not valid.

But doesn't return this fatal "fatal error" message back to porcelain. How can I echo this error back?

**Edit:**
Porcelain code:

```
Porcelain.shell(". #{Path.join(:code.priv_dir(:hub), "scripts/copy_site_to_s3.sh")}")
```

I know the possible solution would be to use `exec` instead of `shell` but this is more of an example, I have a couple of slightly more complicated but similar shell scripts, facing the same problem.

Another script/example(I am testing failures):

Invoking with:

```
result = Porcelain.shell(". #{Path.join(:code.priv_dir(:hub), 
    "scripts/git_clone_pull.sh")} #{github}"
)
IO.inspect result
```

Script:

```
if cd frontend; then git reset --hard && git pull; else git clone $1 frontend; fi
```

It properly fails with:

> fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://github.com/x/frontend.git/'

But porcelain result fails to capture message:

```
%Porcelain.Result{err: nil, out: "", status: 128}
```

Comment: Can you post the Porcelain code you used to invoke this script?

Comment: are there any unescaped characters in your bucket string or something like this? what is the bucket string you’re using to test it?

Comment: Dogbert, updated question. mad.meesh bucket is on purpose wrong, I am trying to write failing test :)

Comment: Why are you echoing at the end? That disposes the previous return code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That was just one of many tries :) I tried without(and updated example without) but the same result - No output back to porcelain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’ll check the documentation for [`Porcelain.{exec,shell}/3` options](https://hexdocs.pm/porcelain/Porcelain.html#exec/3), you’ll see:

> `:err` — specify the way stderr will be passed back to Elixir.
> Possible values are the same as for `:out`. In addition, it accepts the atom `:out` which denotes redirecting `stderr` to `stdout`.
>
> ***Caveat:* when using `Porcelain.Driver.Basic`, the only supported values are `nil` (`stderr` will be printed to the terminal) and `:out`.**

Emphasis is mine. That caveat might be easily proven in the less cumbersome environment, without involving `AWS` and any other 3<sup>rd</sup> parties:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ Porcelain.shell("ls --gg", err: {:append, "error.log"}) 
#⇒ ls: unrecognized option '--gg'
#  Try 'ls --help' for more information.
#  %Porcelain.Result{err: {:append, "error.log"}, out: "", status: 2}

iex|2 ▶ ls "error.log"
# [ERROR] No such file or directory error.log
```

**But we still have `:out` option!**

```rb
iex|3 ▶ Porcelain.shell(">&2 echo 'error'", err: :out) 
%Porcelain.Result{err: :out, out: "error\n", status: 0}

iex|4 ▶ Porcelain.shell("ls --gg", err: :out)          
%Porcelain.Result{
  err: :out,
  out: "ls: unrecognized option '--gg'\nTry 'ls --help' for more information.\n",
  status: 2
}
```

Naya, luckily even `Basic` driver might redirect `:err` to `:out`. That said, you have two options:

- use `err: :out` parameter, pattern match to `when status > 0` and examine standard output, or:
- use [`Porcelain.Driver.Goon`](https://hexdocs.pm/porcelain/Porcelain.Driver.Goon.html) driver and deal with your `stderr` stream like a profi.